# attempt to index nil with leaderstats

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I'm making a game where you ram cars into houses and it unanchored the parts that are touched by a part in the front of the car. I want to have it so that whenever you unanchor a part, you get a coin

```lua
local HitPart = script.Parent

local function onTouch(otherPart)

    local player = otherPart.Parent

    if otherPart then

        local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(otherPart.Parent.Name)

        if otherPart then

            game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.coins.Value = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.coins.Value + 1 

        end

    end

end

HitPart.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

HitPart is the part that is touching the other parts. However, I keep getting "attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'" error. does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the leaderstats inside the player? Here's an [in-depth article](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Leaderboards) about In-game leaderboards by Roblox

Comment: Yeah I added the leaderstats

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are trying to access the `leaderstats` of a player that doesn't exist.

You have a few issues.

- Since this is (probably) a Script, `game.Players.LocalPlayer` doesn't exist. `LocalPlayer` only exists in LocalScripts.
- Since the Touched signal will fire for any object that touches it, you need to add safety checks that the `player` object actually exists

To make finding a player easier, I would recommend the [Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter function](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players#GetPlayerFromCharacter). You pass it a Model from the Workspace, and it tells you if you've got a Player.

```lua
local HitPart = script.Parent

local function onTouch(otherPart)

    local characterModel = otherPart.Parent
    local player = game.Players:FindPlayerFromCharacter(characterModel)

    if player then
        local coins = player.leaderstats.coins
        coins.Value = coins.Value + 1 
    end
end

HitPart.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

Comment: The Script doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Is nothing happening? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: nothings happenig