# roblox studio script problems

Tags: lua, scripting, game-development, roblox

I am making a game where when a part at the front of a car touches another part, the other part becomes unanchored. I am making a different script that gives the player a coin every time they do this. Yes, I have already made a leaderstats script. code:

```
function onPartTouched(otherPart)
    
    local characterModel = otherPart.Parent
    
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(characterModel)

    if player then
        
        local coins = player.leaderstats.coins
        coins.Value = coins.Value + 1 
    end
end
```

Comment: What is the problem? You've explained what you're trying to do, but you haven't mentioned what isn't working.

Comment: This also seems to be an extension of your earlier question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73128503/attempt-to-index-nil-with-leaderstats

Comment: The problem is that the script isnt working, there isnt a physical error

Answer (score 0):

You do actually have to attach the function lol

```lua
function onPartTouched(otherPart)
    
    local characterModel = otherPart.Parent
    
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(characterModel)

    if player then
        
        local coins = player.leaderstats.coins
        coins.Value = coins.Value + 1 
    end
end

MyPart.Touched:Connect(onPartTouched)
```

Comment: MyPart is nil, you dont define it in the code